# python add results from different lists to single list

Tags: python, list

I need to write a function zipper(l1, l2, l3) that accepts three lists of arbitrary length, containing elements of an arbitrary type.

The function returns a list containing all elements from these three lists ordered in the following way: element 1 of list 1, element 1 of list 2, element 1 of list 3, element 2 of list 1, element 2 of list 2, etc. A list stops contributing to the final list when its elements are exhaused.

I've tried using this code:

```
def zipper(l1,l2,l3):
    results = []
    length_1 = len(l1) - 1
    length_2 = len(l2) - 1
    length_3 = len(l3) - 1
    g = True
    h = True
    t = True
    i = 0
    while(g and h and t):
        if(length_1 <= i and g):
            results.append(l1[i])
        if(length_2 <= i and h):
            results.append(l2[i])
        if(length_3 <= i and t):
            results.append(l3[i])
        if(i > length_1):
            g = False
        elif(i > length_2):
            h = False
        elif(i > length_3):
            t = False

        i += 1
    return results

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l3 = [[1,2], [1,2,3], "test", 300]

print(zipper(l1, l2, l3))
```

In the example, the result should be:

```
[1, 'a', [1, 2], 2, 'b', [1, 2, 3], 3, 'c', 'test', 4, 300, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I'm not clear on whether the important part is the development of your own algorithm for this, or the result.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that's similar to using `zip_longest` and `filter`, except that it does it manually. Of course, in real code it's better to use the standard library functions, but it can be a fun learning exercise to implement the functionality yourself.

This code will take any number of lists or other iterables. It creates an infinite generator from each of the iterables. The infinite generators yield a sentinel object called `Done` when an iterable has run out elements.

We simply loop over a list of these generators, adding the non-`Done` elements to our final `result` list, stopping when all the generators yield `Done`.

```
class Done:
    pass

def forever(it):
    for i in iter(it):
        yield i
    while True:
        yield Done

def zipper(*iterables):
    gens = [forever(it) for it in iterables]
    result = []
    while True:
        a = [u for u in [next(g) for g in gens] if u is not Done]
        if a == []:
            break
        result.extend(a)
    return result

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l3 = [[1,2], [1,2,3], "test", 300]

print(zipper(l1, l2, l3))
```

**output**

```
[1, 'a', [1, 2], 2, 'b', [1, 2, 3], 3, 'c', 'test', 4, 300, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify greatly by using `.pop` for lists.
This will loop while there are still elements in any of your lists, and if the list still has items it will pop off the first element of the input and append it to your results list.

```
def zipper(l1, l2, l3):
    results = []
    while l1 or l2 or l3:
        if l1:
            results.append(l1.pop(0))
        if l2:
            results.append(l2.pop(0))
        if l3:
            results.append(l3.pop(0))

     return results
```

Comment: Very compact, considering it doesn't need to import itertools. But maybe you should make copies of the passed in lists, since it may not be desirable to remove the elements of the original lists.

Comment: And if you're making a copy anyway, you might reverse them, so you don't have to keep popping from the start (which isn't very efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `itertools.izip_longest`: for python 2x

```
>>> import itertools
>>> filter(lambda x: x!=None, [y for x in itertools.izip_longest(l1,l2,l3) for y in x])
[1, 'a', [1, 2], 2, 'b', [1, 2, 3], 3, 'c', 'test', 4, 300, 5, 6, 7]
```

use `itertools.zip_longest`: for python 3x

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x!=None, [y for x in itertools.zip_longest(l1,l2,l3) for y in x]))
[1, 'a', [1, 2], 2, 'b', [1, 2, 3], 3, 'c', 'test', 4, 300, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: This will remove zeros from the lists, which doesn't seem intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip_longest,chain
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l3 = [[1,2], [1,2,3], "test", 300]
a =list(chain(*(filter(None, pair) for pair in izip_longest(l1,l2,l3))))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a bit and it does what you want it to do, if I understood you correctly.

```
   def zipper(l1,l2,l3):
       results = []
       g, h, t = True, True, True
       i = 0
       while(g or h or t):
           if(len(l1) > i):
               results.append(l1[i])
           else:
               g=False
           if(len(l2) > i):
               results.append(l2[i])
           else:
               h=False
           if(len(l3) > i):
               results.append(l3[i])
           else:
               t=False

           i += 1
       return results

   l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
   l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
   l3 = [[1,2], [1,2,3], "test", 300]

   print(zipper(l1, l2, l3))
```

The output is

```
    [1, 'a', [1, 2], 2, 'b', [1, 2, 3], 3, 'c', 'test', 4, 300, 5, 6, 7]
```